# What Does The C readline() Function Below Mean?

Tags: c, arrays, string, function, modular

I took some sample test about C programming. I had to solve a problem by making a new function which usesd the existing functions. One of them is in the code below, but I didn't know what this one is for.

```
char* readLine() {
size_t alloc_length = 1024;
size_t data_length = 0;
char* data = malloc(alloc_length);

while (true) {
    char* cursor = data + data_length;
    char* line = fgets(cursor, alloc_length - data_length, stdin);

    if(!line) { break; }

    data_length += strlen(cursor);

    if(data_length < alloc_length -1 || data[data_length - 1] == '\n') { break; }

    size_t new_length = alloc_length << 1;
    data = realloc(data, new_length);

    if(!data) { break; }

    alloc_length = new_length;
}

if (data[data_length - 1] == '\n') {
    data[data_length - 1] = '\0';
}

data = realloc(data, data_length);

return data;
}
```

What does the function do and what does it mean? (*PS: sorry bad grammar)

Comment: It's reading a line of text from `stdin`. It's handling a line that can be an arbitrary length (or until memory runs out at least). It starts off with an initial buffer size of 1024 and doubles the buffer each time it fills up.

Comment: If you still don't understand it then step through it line by line on paper or in a debugger. If there is a specific line of code you don't understand then ask about that rather than the whole function so that you can get a more targetted answer.

Comment: This is a bad example on how to use `realloc`.  Please do not try to learn from it.